# Update a global variable from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 variables which are concatenated into another variable.  On the click of a button the values of the variables should update and also the concatenated variable, but the global variable is keeping the original value.

```
<button class="filter period" data-sort-value="number" data-period="ltd">LTD</button>
<button class="filter period" data-sort-value="number" data-period="r3">R+3</button>
<button class="filter period" data-sort-value="number" data-period="r12">R+12</button>
<button class="filter period" data-sort-value="number" data-period="rtodec">RTODEC</button>
<script>

    var region = "ww";
    var period = "ltd";

    var finalFilter = "data-" + region + "-" + period;

    $('button.filter').on('click', function () {

        if ( $(this).hasClass("period") ) {

            period = $(this).attr('data-period');
            console.log(finalFilter);
            console.log(period);
            updatedFinalFilter();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This should work - what's your issue? (apart from the missing `updatedFinalFilter` method). Most likely the `updatedFinalFilter` method is in a different scope.

Comment: Can you show us your updatedFinalFilter method?

Comment: Are you expecting `"data-" + region + "-" + period;` to be dynamic and automatically update the value of `finalFilter` whenever `period` (or `region`) changes?  That's not how variables work in JS.

Comment: Yes, i want that finalFilter to be update automatically when one of period or region change value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, i want that finalFilter to be update automatically when one of period or region change value

The only way to make that happen is to actually update it.  Variables in JavaScript don't update automatically based on the expression you used to set them the first time.  After:

```
var finalFilter = "data-" + region + "-" + period;
```

has run, `finalFilter` is purely set to `"data-ww-ltd"` - it has no knowledge of or link to `region` or `period`.

So before you call `updatedFinalFilter()`, you'd have to re-evaluate the expression:

```
var region = "ww";
var period = "ltd";

var finalFilter = "data-" + region + "-" + period;

$('button.filter').on('click', function () {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("period") ) {

        period = $(this).attr('data-period');

        finalFilter = "data-" + region + "-" + period;

        console.log(finalFilter);
        console.log(period);
        updatedFinalFilter();
    }

});
```

Note the lack of `var` when we update it from in the function - you don't want to redeclare it there otherwise it will become a *different* `finalFilter` locally scoped to that function.